# alter table truncate partition error with redaction

Tags: oracle

Does anybody know why Oracle (using 12c) is throwing an error when redaction policies are on a partitioned table and then **alter table ... truncate partion .. update global indexes** is run?
It is in fact the update global indexes that's throwing the exception.

I can easily work around this by adding an exception handler and run a delete statement instead.. it just is a lot slower.

test case:

```
drop table test;

create table test (
  f1 number,
  f2 number,
  constraint pk_test primary key (f1)
)
partition by list (f1) (
  partition dim_0 values (0),
  partition dim_1 values (1),
  partition dim_2 values (2),
  partition dim_3 values (3),
  partition dim_4 values (4),
  partition dim_5 values (5)
);


insert into test (f1, f2)
with r(f1, f2) as (
  select 1, 2 from dual
  union all
  select f1+1, f2+2 from r
  where f1<5
)
select f1, f2
from r;

-- select the data, without redaction
select *
from test;

-- add a redaction policy to the table
begin
  dbms_redact.add_policy(
    object_schema        => 'HPF',
    object_name          => 'test',
    column_name          => 'f1',
    policy_name          => 'hide_f1',
    function_type        => dbms_redact.full,
    function_parameters  => dbms_redact.redact_us_ssn_f5,
    expression           => '1=1'
  );
end;
/

-- select the data, with redaction
select *
from test;

-- trunacte test
alter table test truncate partition dim_5 update global indexes;
-- drop test
alter table test drop partition dim_5 update global indexes;


--============> OUTPUT:

table TEST created.
5 rows inserted.
F1                     F2                     
---------------------- ---------------------- 
1                      2                      
2                      4                      
3                      6                      
4                      8                      
5                      10                     

anonymous block completed
F1                     F2                     
---------------------- ---------------------- 
0                      2                      
0                      4                      
0                      6                      
0                      8                      
0                      10                     


Error starting at line 51 in command:
alter table test truncate partition dim_5 update global indexes
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-28081: Insufficient privileges - the command references a redacted object.
00604. 00000 -  "error occurred at recursive SQL level %s"
*Cause:    An error occurred while processing a recursive SQL statement
           (a statement applying to internal dictionary tables).
*Action:   If the situation described in the next error on the stack
           can be corrected, do so; otherwise contact Oracle Support.

Error starting at line 53 in command:
alter table test drop partition dim_5 update global indexes
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-28081: Insufficient privileges - the command references a redacted object.
00604. 00000 -  "error occurred at recursive SQL level %s"
*Cause:    An error occurred while processing a recursive SQL statement
           (a statement applying to internal dictionary tables).
*Action:   If the situation described in the next error on the stack
           can be corrected, do so; otherwise contact Oracle Support.
```